# Lattice: Plotting two lines with different scale and axes in the same panel

Tags: r, graph, scale, lattice, axis-labels

I have something like this:

```
a <- c(1,4,2,8)
b <- c(100,80,40, 0)
c <- 1:4
x <- rep("foo",4)
y <- rep("bar",4)

df1 <- data.frame(c, y = a, gr = x)
df2 <- data.frame(c, y = b, gr = y)
df <- rbind(df1,df2)

xyplot(y ~ c, data = df, type = "l", group = df$gr)
```

Results in this:

[image]

I am looking for a way that would allow me to change the scale so that the blue line fills the entire panel area, and add a corresponding axis to the right side of the plot.

If adding the axis is too hard, then it is not a requirement. The units on the y axis are arbitrary anyway (in my own data). Maybe a way to normalize the data would work?

There are several answers on this site, but they all work on the basic graphics of R, and none using lattice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
library(latticeExtra)
library(dplyr)
dfgr <-df %>% filter(gr == "foo")
dfbar <-df %>% filter(gr == "bar")
obj1 <- xyplot(y ~ c, dfgr, type = "l")
obj2 <- xyplot(y ~ c, dfbar, type = "l")
doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, add.ylab2 = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for pointing out one of the nice features of `latticeExtra`.  But there is no need to load `dplyr` and create 2 new data frames.  `obj1 <- xyplot(y ~ c, dfgr, type = "l",subset=gr=="foo")`, etc. is more direct and no less clear.

Comment: Oops. That should be `obj1 <- xyplot(y ~ c, df, type = "l",subset=gr=="foo")` (I didn't create `dfgr`).